# Best way to validate infopath form - specific scenario

Tags: 2010, infopath, forms-services

I have this infopath form with 8 fields named:

```
Field1
Field2
Field3
Field4
etc.
```

How should I go to validate the form in a way that I cannot have duplicate values on those fields.

I cannot use code-behind because I dont have access to the central admin, plus a code-behind sandbox solution is too buggy for my like, keep getting random errors when publishing, using it. So I am looking for a no-code solution. I am using Sharepoint Server 2010.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to validate among these fields or against DB values for each field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I end up doing a full compare of all the possible combinations:

```
8 choose 2 = 28.
```

Thats a lot of rules. There is another limitation, one item cannot have more than 6 rules (or at least i thought so), looks like this limitation is only on the designer to overcome this limitation do the folloing:

In the Rule condition **select expression** and you can insert as many comparisiona as you want like:

```
. = ../my:Field2 or . = ../my:Field3 or . = ../my:Field4 ...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to just compare values to make sure there are no duplicates among them, you could create a validation rule on each of the fields that compares the values of each of the affected fields every time the value changes, and throws a validation error if duplicates are found.

Comment: Thats what I end up doing. See my answer for a more detailed solution